# Can't surf from PC when using Android as hotspot

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace, tethering

I turned on mobile data and hotspot in my Samsung Galaxy Ace (On a Philippine carrier called "Globe"). I can surf websites just fine directly on Android.

Now, I connect my PC to Android's hotspot, it connects but it can't surf or ping websites.

It used to work before (used it some months ago) but now it doesn't. What could the problem?

Edit:

`ipconfig` screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This could be a local networking issue. Can you get the network configuration info from your PC? If you're on Windows, could you update your question with the output of `ipconfig` from a Command Prompt while connected to your hotspot? (Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/58143/edit) your question with the information)

Comment: What carrier is the device on?

Comment: @dotVezz updated with `ipconfig`

Comment: @Compro01 This is a Philippine carrier, `Globe`.

Comment: I had the same, although intermittent, problem recently. Whilst it would be OK for periods of time, my connection would drop and be unable to connect to sites, whilst the phone connection was still OK. In the end I put it down to the fact I was still connected to my wired LAN through which I would normally connect to the internet (my main broadband connection was down for a few days, hence why I was tethering via mobile). If I disconnected completely from my LAN (which wasn't desirable) I would regain the mobile connection.

Comment: @w3d I see however my LAN is completely disabled when I'm connected to Android.

Comment: Out of curiousity: Could you post the output of the following in Command Prompt? `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @dotVezz Timeout 100% loss. But, interestingly if my manually set my WiFi Adapter to use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` as DNS servers, I can ping `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, however still not browse or ping any sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built in Wifi Tethering in Settings, then Android might have automatically misconfigured the iproutes.

You can try clearing the data on the tethering app and settings to refresh the configuration. Open `Settings` -> `Applications` -> click `Settings` -> `Clear Data`.

Same procedure for the tethering app, Open `Settings` -> `Applications` -> click `">your tethering app here<` -> `Clear Data`

and to add, I'm also a Globe/Sun subscriber :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping DNS eg google DNS "ping 8.8.8.8 -t" if it replied, then your problem might be browser specific. Check if you do not have proxy settings set on your browser.

If it does not reply, make sure you do not have a VPN software installed on your Android device, Tethering will not work with VPN installed on Android. Also make sure you do not have active VPN on your PC too as this will change the default route of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving DNS configuration manually. It solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some mobile operators block tethering by checking the browser "User-Agent" when you request a web page...I don't know if this still happens but it was widespread a few years ago.  Basically if the User-Agent doesn't say "I'm a phone" the request is blocked.  There are ways to change the User-Agent on some PC browsers so it might be worth giving that a try.